# Entsprechende Satz : "on the same page"

Tags: phrase-request

Ich schreibe eine E-mail und suche eine/n entsprechende/n Redewendung/Satz für "on the same page". Es bedeutet etwas wie "wir haben alle die gleiche Informationen und alle verstehen einander"

Vielen Dank für die Hilfe (und bitte, korrigiert meinen ersten Satz auch in den Comments vielleicht. Ich weiß nicht, wie man das sagt. Sagt man eine entsprechende Redewendung für/auf/zum ... d.h welches Präposition)

Comment: "Redewendung für" ist richtig. In deiner Langfassung kannst du das zweite "alle" streichen; nicht nur ist es obsolet, es könnte auch so verstanden werden, dass es über das das "wir" aus dem ersten Satz hinausgeht! Für die Übersetzung mag etwas mehr sprachlicher Kontext interessant sein. Eine ähnlich kompakte Übersetzung gibt es mglw nicht; damit wäre zB interessant, ob du fragen willst, "Are we all on the same page?", oder aussagen willst, "Just so we are all on the same page."

Comment: Also, a semi-serious proposal for informal contexts: "Alles klar?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In offizielleren Kontexten würde ich Folgendes sagen:

> …, damit (so that) wir alle auf demselben / dem gleichen Stand sind.

Es gibt auch einige andere Wege, die aber teilweise etwas umgangssprachlich/salopp sind.

> …, damit wir alle wissen, worüber wir reden/wo wir stehen/was Sache ist/…
>
> …, damit wir nicht aneinander vorbeireden.

Comment: Zum Umgangssprachlichen der letzten beiden Beispiele: in privater Kommunikation ist das vollkommen OK. `"was Sache ist"` ist tatsächlich sehr salopp und könnte als oberflächlich angesehen werden; "`wo wir stehen`" ebenfalls und könnte darüber hinaus auch misverstanden werden (`stehen` = Projektfortschritt, statt z.B. `Wissensstand`) (wobei sich die Bedeutung aus dem Kontext ergeben sollte). Die letzte Phrase finde ich auch in geschäftlicher Kommunikation akzeptabel.

Comment: Der Vollständigkeit halber: `d'accord sein` steht im Duden und man könnte es hier wohl auch verwenden.

Comment: Danke für die Antworten. Das ist genau was ich wollte. Und danke für die andere Vorschläge, die alle sehr nützlich sind.